# Mongoose complex query for update and insert data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have model like this:

```
var MyModel = new mongoose.Schema({
 key: String,
 array_values : [{
    value: String,
    counter: { type: Number, default: 1}
}];
```

I need to insert a key-value pair, so that:

1. In case there is no `key`, then a new document was added;
2. In case there is a `key`, then:

   - if there is a `value` in the `array_values`, the value of the `counter` field has increased,
   - else if there is no such `value`, it was simply added new object `{key, counter}` to the `array_value`.

For example, there is a document:

```
{
 key: "key",
 array_values: [{value: "value", counter: 1}]
}
```

when inserting the `{key: "key", value: "value"}` should be:

```
{
 key: "key",
 array_values: [{value: "value", counter: 2}]
}
```

when inserting a `{key: "key_1", value: "value"}`, a document should be added:

```
{
 key: "key",
 array_values: [{value: "value", counter: 1}]
},
{
 key: "key_1",
 array_values: [{value: "value", counter: 1}]
}
```

when inserting the `{key: "key", value: "value_1"}` should be:

```
{
 key: "key",
 array_values: [
    {value: "value", counter: 1}, 
    {value: "value_1", counter: 1}]
}
```

Is it possible to do this using one query?

Before that, I used `.findOne({key: 'findingKey'})`, and then processed the result, but it was very slow, to process a large amount of `key-value`

UPD:

Here is how I tried to do:

I added a static function:

```
MyModel.statics.addKeyValue = async function (key, value) {
    let item = await this.findOne({key: key}).exec();
    if (item) {
        const arr = item.array_values;
        let findItem = arr.find((arrItem) => {
            return arrItem.value === value;
        });

        if (findItem !== undefined) {
            findItem.count += 1;
        } else {
            item.array_values.push({value: value, counter: 1});
        }
        await item.save();
    } else {
        await this.create({
            key : key,
            array_values: [{value: value, counter: 1}]
        });
    }
};
```

But to insert 170 thousand values it took more than 10 hours

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following query. It will **find** a document with provided **key** from request body, and it will update or create depends on the result return from mongoose query.

```
MyModel.findOne({key: req.body.key}, (err, result) => {
    if (!result) {
        result = new Model();
        result.key = req.body.key;
        result.array_values = [];
    }
    result.array_values.push(req.body.array_values);
    result.save();
})
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I did something like this (now I’ll update my question). Your answer does not include the counter field. Once, when I was processing a lot of key-value pairs, it took a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `findOneAndUpdate`? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

May be this will work for you 
eg:-

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { key: 'key3' }, 
    { $inc: { 'array_values.counter': 1 } }, 
    { upsert: true }
)
```

This will not work for all case it will work for the 1st and 2nd case.
Let me know it is working or not

Comment: In the form in which you wrote it works. But values in the array are not inserted